# Powershell does not wait for download to finish

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-4.0

I am fairly new to Powershell and I am already faced with quite an annoying issue which is probably due to my inexperience. Google has proved helpful for what follows.

Context:

I am executing a Powershell script on an Azure Windows Server via Custom Extensions.
The script performs a series of sequential steps, each step wrapped into a function. 
The functions are called one after the other. 
One of the functions downloads a biggish (yes there is no such a word) ZIP file.
The next function then attempts to unzip the file contents to a directory but constantly fails with "file does not exist" errors, meaning that the zipped file that the step is attempting to access does not exist. This is false though because the preceeding file download step does indeed download the zipped file and I can prove that using the `Test-Path` command. 
It's almost as if Powershell is TOO FAST (if there's such) and doesn't wait for the file download step to completely finish before executing the unzip function.

Reason I say that the function seems too fast is because if I include a `Start-Sleep` command an sleep for 20 seconds after the file download statement, the unzip function works fine as it can locate the downloaded zipped file.

The obvious issue with the `Start-Sleep` command is that what if my biggish zip file takes more than 
 seconds to download...boom, back to problem.

Question: IS THERE A WAY THAT I CAN TELL POWERSHELL TO WAIT TILL A FUNCTION THAT DOWNLOADS A FILE IS COMPLETELY FINISHED BEFORE EXECUTING THE NEXT FUNCTION?

Here's an example of how my script looks like:

```
function DoSomething {
    param (
        #some params
    )

    #do something...
}


function Download-File {
    param (
        #some params
    )

    #FILE DOWNLOAD FUNCTION THAT DOWNLOADS A BIGGISH ZIP FILE
    #......................I am using Azure CLI to download the zipped file from BLOB storage

    az storage blob download --account-name $storageAccountName --container-name $storageContainerName --name $fullyQualifiedFileName --file .\$fileName --auth-mode login;
}

function Unzip-File {
    param (
        #some params
    )

    #ATTEMPT TO UNZIP FILE
}

function DoSomethingElse {
    param (
        #some params
    )

    #do something...
}

DoSomething;
Download-File;
Unzip-File; #This guy seems too quick, eager to access the zipped file downloaded in the preceeding step...whilst the preceeding step is not done downloading
DoSomethingElse;


#PLEASE HELP :(
```

Comment: If you pipe `Download-File` to `Out-Null` it should wait.

Comment: If the download is handled by a job, such as by using start-job then you can use wait-job

Comment: [The `azure storage blob download` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download) don't mention asynchronous behavior. If the file really does predictably appear eventually, as a workaround you can wait in a `Test-Path` loop until the file exists, using `Start-Sleep` to sleep a little between calls.

Comment: @mklement0 so generally, can this be accepted as a powershell weekness? The general consensus around the internet is that you should use `Start-Sleep`. But why?!! I read that internal powershell commands have a 'built in' wait functionality. But why is this not a language/framework feature? Good G*d, how is everyone automating then using Powershell with this weekness? Anywho, thanks for your input, I will try the do while and pause a few seconds when $fileExists = False

Comment: No, it's not a PowerShell weakness: PowerShell reliably executes console applications synchronously, so as long as such an application is designed to have completed its task by the time it exits, everything works as expected. I don't have access to Azure, so I can't help you with your specific command. The behavior seems strange to me, but without additional information the problem cannot be diagnosed. The loop-with-`Start-Sleep` recommendation is just a _workaround_, if you cannot find and fix the root cause.

Comment: Ok I solved the issue here. Put simply, Azure CLI is the devil on Powershell, doesn't play nice at all. I installed Azure Powershell and all was okay, no need to Start-Sleep between commands as the Blob Storage Download Azure Powershell commands have a built in 'wait till I am done' function? I don't know, but it works way more smoothely than Azure CLI. Thanks for the engagement!